# Default checked radio not changing the checked attribute on change of selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a radio group having Male and Female as options. Depending on what is stored in database i am having a default checked radio button.

[image: This is the default selection]

Now over inspect element i am getting what i needed :

[image: This is the inspect element of the radios]

But when i select female lets say, the JQuery is still taking the value of Male radio.

```
$("input[name=detail-gender]").val();
```

It is giving me value "M" even if i select Female, in that case it should have resulted in "F".

```
$("input[name=detail-gender]").change(function() {
    alert($("input[name=detail-gender]").val());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [**:checked selector**](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

```
$("input[name=detail-gender]:checked").val();
```

Comment: Oh.. I see what was the problem. Thanks for pointing out though :)